# JQuery only adding to children of odd even index

Tags: jquery

I have the following JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('tr').hover(function () {            
        $(this).children().addClass("color2");
        $(this).children().removeClass("color1");
    });
});
```

But I only want it to add onto a `td` element which has an even index (including 0)

Comment: [:even](http://api.jquery.com/even-selector/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>replace `$(this)` with `$('td:even', this)`.</s>

Edit:

I didn't see `children()` the first time. So, replace `$(this).children()` with `$('td:even', this)`.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the selector, add the [`:even`](http://api.jquery.com/even-selector/) selector

```
$('tr > td:even').hover(function() {
  // ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/children/) the `children()` function can have a filter argument. In your case you want to only select (td) children that are even. So change `children()` in `children('td:even')`